# No Activity found to handle Intent com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, instagram

In our React Native app, we're trying to have our users share specific images straight to either feed or story depending on a selection within our view/component.

When we try to share using "com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_FEED" directly, it works perfectly in a consisten manner.

However when trying to share using "com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY" directly we get the following error:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY > typ=image/* flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.instagram.android (has extras) }

We've gotten it to work only with one device (specifically using a Samsung Note 8), but our other test devices all have that error pop up.

Here's our code:

```
@ReactMethod
public void shareWithInstagram(String fileName, String base64str, String mode, Callback callback,
        Callback secondCallback) {

    this.callback = callback;

    String type = "image/*";

    File media = saveImage(getReactApplicationContext(), fileName, base64str);

    if (isAppInstalled("com.instagram.android") == false) {
        callback.invoke("Sorry, instagram is not installed in your device.");
    } else {
        if (media.exists()) {
            Intent share = new Intent("com.instagram.share." + mode);
            share.setType(type);
            share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

            share.setDataAndType(uri, type);
            share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

            if (currentActivity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(share, 0) != null) {

                currentActivity.startActivityForResult(share, INSTAGRAM_SHARE_REQUEST);
            } else {
                callback.invoke("Sorry, an error ocurred.");
            }
        } else {
            callback.invoke("Sorry, image could not be loaded from disk.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

Comment: We're already doing that...

Comment: Hi, for us it was the "type", it needed to be "video/mp4", could be that "image/*" isn't allowed.

Comment: @tobidude it works for me your suggestion. I think you need to convert to answer from comment.

Comment: Did it! Happy for an uprate.

Answer (score 5):

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file is probably missing an important element: `<queries/>`.

As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) say

> Specifies the set of other apps that an app intends to interact with. These other apps can be specified by package name, by intent signature, or by provider authority

In my case, after adding the following lines in the manifest file (inside `manifest` tag, not in `application`) everything started working.

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name='com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY' />
        <data android:mimeType='image/*' />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably happening because the activity with the action `com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY` has `android:enabled="false"` in Instagram manifest. The `com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_FEED` action activity does not have this.

You can see that sharing to the Story is also not available if you try to share an image from the gallery.

The solution is simple: **you need to restart Instagram after you have logged in**. Then it will become available. This is probably an Instagram precaution against showing multiple Instagram actions in app chooser if user actually does not use Instagram.

---

Now this becomes quite funny:

> our other test devices all have that error pop up

..it happens because when you try it on another device, you just install Instagram, log into your testing account and start trying .. and it never works because you first need to restart the Instagram app! :)

Comment: this is not the solution. we cannot expect user to restart phone so they can use our apps.. :( shame that `com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY` is in `Facebook`'s official documentation, but not working -.-

Comment: Users are already logged in the Instagram app. The issue is only happening when you install Instagram for the first time and log in for the first time, until you restart the app (or it terminates naturally by not using it for a while, or user reboots the phone). The important note here is, that **this will not happen to users in real-world conditions**.

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same problem. I tried to restart Instagram/Device and it still not working. Any idea? I'm testing in a real device. Not in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

For us it was the "type", it seems "image/*" isn't allowed.

Using "video/mp4" worked!