# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY}

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

as mentioned in Facebook developers, the way to publish a story to Instagram is to use the following code. one of solutions as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716819/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-com-instagram-share-add-to-story) suggests that it will be resolved once Instagram is restarted. although it isn't working with us

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "jpg");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra("content_url", "https://www.yallasolutions.com");
    this.grantUriPermission(
            "com.instagram.android", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
try {
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.instagram.android",0);
        Log.e("test","instagram was found");
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("test","instagram is not installed !!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    Activity activity = this;
    if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null)
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

i have tried both `ADD_TO_STORY` and `ADD_TO_FEED` and both return same error.

Here is a reference to my manifest as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kareem.test">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did u find any solutions for this issue?

Comment: @AhmedFayez no not yet unfortunately

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you tried using another device?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the `<queries>` element in your manifest file. Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68844188/4275917) in that other post.

Answer (score -1):

Check the website

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

You have to create an account and put upur app on this website.